# $f(x,y)=2xe^{x^2-y}$ for $0<x<1$ and $y>x^2$ find the marginal density function of $f_Y$

Tags: probability

$f(x,y)=2xe^{x^2-y}$ for $0<x<1$ and $y>x^2$ find the marginal density function of $f_Y$

[image]

I'm confused with why $0<y<1$ you integrate from $[0,\sqrt y]$

I'm guessing it's because $y>x^2$? So if $y\in [0,1]$ then x has to be less than that, which means it has to be less than the square root of w.e y is?

and why for $y\ge 1$ then you integrate from $0<x<1$

This one I don't get why it's $y \ge 1$? Cause y should not equal x ever according to the constraints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $y \geq 1$ then $y >x^{2}$ automatically whenever $0<x<1$ so there is no additional constraint on $x$. When $y <1$ you have to take into account the condition $y >x^{2}$ which forces $x$ to be less than $\sqrt y$. As a general rule you have to choose the ranges for the variables of integration taking all given constraints into account.